# PHP HTML submitting only certain info in a table

Tags: php, html

I am using php to generate a table with values from a mysql server.  Beside each row I have a button that deletes that row.  How can I submit info to the php page that will perform the deletion so that it knows what row I want it to delete?

Right now I have my submit button named so that the name changes with a counter which increases after each row.  I then want to check if the submit button is set then take the values for that submit buttons name which will be the same as my row name.

Would this work? or is there a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the rows unique key/id to identify the correct row. This id can then be used to ensure that the correct row will be deleted. When there is no such unique id in your table, have a look at [primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

Comment: Even if I assign an id to each row, how do would I get the values to perform my mysql query?

Comment: You can, for example, put a link next to each row having the id in the query string for a script. E.g. `/delete.php?id=123`. The `delete.php` just has to read out the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php) variable `$_GET['id']` in order to get the correct id.